# I can't boot from live-usb or access GRUB or repair GRUB or install GRUB if it turns out isn't installed

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, boot-repair

The only way I know how to describe my problem is to go step by step:    
**1+** I bought a Dell Optiplex 330 at a thrift shop, installed Lubuntu 16.04 and tested it. It worked fine and I stored it away until I would have time to make it useful to me.

 **2+** I have time now so I cleaned it and upgraded the RAM. When I turned it on Lubuntu wouldn't boot, nor would a Lubuntu Live-usb (although the live-session menu **does work**, you know the thing with "Try before installing" and memtest).

**3+** I tested the new RAM w/ live-usb memtest and Dell's built in one, it's fine.

**4+** I used the boot-repair-disk (**which completely boots and functions normally**), and did the recommended repair option. It worked and I could boot Lubuntu from the HDD, but I want to install Ubuntu-Studio so I tried it's live-usb and it failed the same as in **2+**.
**5+** I'm not sure exactly what order I did things after that but right now I have Windows 7 temporarily installed (**which boots and functions normally**).

**6+** I don't know if GRUB is installed anymore. Boot repair does not restore it and holding shift at boot no longer brings up the menu.
**Some Additional info:**
**+** I have the same exact problem with fedora live-usb.
**+** Only Gnome-disks and Dell bios know that my HDD is 80 gb, Gparted and Windows think it's 75~ish.
 Please ask me questions if you think you might be able to help, I probably won't answer right away but i'll get to within a day or two.

**Boot-Info Summary:** https://paste.ubuntu.com/23665755/

**Image shown when trying to boot from usb:** [image: boot-fail]

**Boot-repair session screensaver (seems wrong to me):** [image: boot-repair]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 64 bit version of Lubuntu?
Can you also boot from liveUSB and test use the system (start file manager, open some game, open a terminal, etc).

Your screenshots don't seem to match. One shows kernel 4.4 and the other shows kernel 3.13. Can you confirm there is only 1 hard drive and a single partition?

Also did you check the cable(s) connection the HD? Maybe one came loose when you cleaned up. These error message in your first screenshot says it can't find the hard drive (uknown block 0,0)

Basically if you can boot from liveUSB and do some things then you should be fine to do a fresh install without problems. From my hazy past recollection I sometimes used to get kernel panics after upgrading to a newer kernel.

Comment: I'm using 64bit ISOs and the CPU is 64bit. There is only one HDD, it's 80Gb and has the 2 default  Windows 7 partitions. I checked the HDD cables and they're as snug as they'll get. The first screenshot is what shows up when I try to boot from a live-usb installer (either "Try before installing " or "Install _distro_". The second screenshot is just something that shows up when I don't touch the keyboard for a while in the boot-repair session, I'm not sure if it's relevant. I think the kernel versions in the screenshots reflect the usbs and not anything installed on my HDD but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

It was the RAM. I don't know why Boot-Repair and Windows were working fine and why no Memtest errors showed up but one of my RAM sticks was faulty and I'm good now. Thanks! You're Welcome!!